# ASP.NET MVC ( Object reference not set to an instance of an object )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, join, include

I have the following problem when displaying list of personal file,
 but I used the (using System.Data.Entity) and (Include) in the query it's not working

Class Model

```
public class PersonalFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public DateTime UploadDateTime { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int? FileCategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FileCategoryId")]
    public virtual FileCategory FileCategory { get; set; }

}
```

Class View Model

```
public class PersonalFileViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FileCategoryId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PersonalFile> PersonalFiles { get; set; }
}
```

Class Model File Category

```
public class FileCategory
{
    public int FileCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public string optionGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PersonalFile> PersonalFile { get; set; }
}
```

Action Method
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
                return HttpNotFound();

```
        var empl = _dbContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(c => c.EmployeeId == id);
        if (empl == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        ViewBag.FileCategoryId = new SelectList(_dbContext.FileCategory, "FileCategoryId", "categoryName" , "optionGroup", 0);

        var vwModel = new PersonalFileViewModel
        {
            EmployeeId = empl.EmployeeId,
            PersonalFiles = _dbContext.PersonalFiles.Include(p => p.Employee).Include(p => p.FileCategory).Where(x => x.EmployeeId == id)
        };


        NameAndImage(empl.EmployeeId);
        return View(vwModel);
    }
```

View

```
foreach (var j in Model.PersonalFiles)
                            {
                                <tr style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">@j.FileName</td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;"> @j.FileCategory.categoryName </td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">@j.UploadDateTime</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href=@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/PersonalFiles/"+j.FilePath) class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Download</a>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { j.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm", onclick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete this file?');" })
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O1Xh.png)

Comment: check if @j.FileCategory is coming null? perhaps thats why it is not retrieving the value of categoryName

Comment: Add a temporary line in your controller: `_dbContext.PersonalFiles.Include(p => p.Employee).Include(p => p.FileCategory).Where(x => x.EmployeeId == id).ToList();` - is the expected data in here? Is it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, make sure that with each `PersonalFile` belongs to `FileCategory` accordingly.

**Secondly**, You should `.ToList()` to force our query to [execute immediately](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-in-linq/) instead.

```
PersonalFiles = _dbContext.PersonalFiles.Include(p => p.Employee).Include(p => p.FileCategory).Where(x => x.EmployeeId == id).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting this line Code on the View

```
@(j.FileCategory == null ? "" : j.FileCategory.categoryName)
```